# Descobrir um valor intermediário entre duas variáveis

Tags: javascript, matemática

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo para o jogo de damas e me deparei com um problema, quando uma peça come a outra, onde preciso saber a posição da peça que foi comida. Conforme a imagem e o código abaixo, sabendo-se o valor de `a` que é a posição atual da peça e `c` a posição futura, preciso descobrir o valor de `b`, que é a posição da peça comida, levando em consideração o padrão de se caso `a - c = 7`, então `b` é igual ou `a - 3` ou `a - 4` ou se caso `a - c = 9`, então `b` é igual ou `a - 4` ou `a - 5`. Como posso descobrir o valor de `b`?

[image: imagem do algoritmo]

```
if (a - c == 7){
   if (a - 3 == b){

   } else
   if (a - 4 == b){

   }
} else
if (a - c == 9){
   if (a - 4 == b){

   } else
   if (a - 5 == b){

   }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro guardar o valor de `a - c` em uma variável e comparar a variável, assim o cálculo não será executado a cada condição `if`

Comment: Não entendi. Você precisa entender o valor de `b` conhecendo apenas a diferença `a-c`?

Comment: Então b seria a posição da peça que foi comida?

Comment: Isso mesmo, @dvd.

Comment: Por que você não representa o tabuleiro com dois inteiros para cada posição? Tipo, em vez de usar a posição `22`, usaria `(2, 5)`

Comment: Até poderia, mas já desenvolvi quase toda a lógica usando um número inteiro pra cada posição. Só falta descobrir qual peça foi comida, para removê-la do tabuleiro.

Comment: Suspeito que isso seja um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy). Se desvendar um pouco mais do código(algoritmo) será mais facil de dar a ajuda apropriada. Certamente terá formas bem mais apropriadas e bem menos enigmáticas de perceber que peças foram comidas.

Comment: @Isac, depende... Na minha pergunta eu abordo o problema X e informo que estou tentando resolver da forma Y com o padrão que percebi entre as posições do tabuleiro, mas nada impede que as outras pessoas tentem resolver de outra forma e/ou com outro padrão. Não é nada impossível, já que se trata de um jogo de tabuleiro popular.

Comment: @mylos isso se chama refatorar. Palavra mágica usada quando se está removendo bugs. Se você não quer refatorar, você está inserindo mais e mais bugs, um madelbug

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, a forma como estou fazendo talvez não seja a melhor, mas não está errada. Escolhi porque é simples e eficiente. Alterar a forma de representação de cada posição agora iria interferir em toda a lógica do algoritmo e eu teria que refazer tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lógica que percebi é a seguinte:

Quando `a - c = 7`, então `a` e `c` poderiam ter os valores:

```
a   c       b
----------------
9   2 --> a - 3 |
10  3 --> a - 3 | --> qualquer "a" dividido por 4 resulta em par (descartando as decimais)
11  4 --> a - 3 |

13  6 --> a - 4 |
14  7 --> a - 4 | --> qualquer "a" dividido por 4 resulta em ímpar (descartando as decimais)
15  8 --> a - 4 |
...
31  24 --> a - 4
```

A cada grupo de 3 valores de `a`, o valor de `b` pode ser `a - 3` ou `a - 4`. Note-se também se eu dividir cada valor de `a` por `4`, terei uma sequência lógica de cada grupo com resultado *ímpar* ou *par* alternadamente de 3 em 3 números.

Logo, `b` seria:

```
var b = ~~(a/4)%2 == 0 ? a - 3 : a - 4;
```

No caso de `a - c = 9`, a mesma lógica se aplica para o valor de `c` em vez de `a` do caso anterior:

```
a   c       b
----------------
10  1 --> a - 4 |
11  2 --> a - 4 | --> qualquer "c" dividido por 4 resulta em par (descartando as decimais)
12  3 --> a - 4 |

14  5 --> a - 5 |
15  6 --> a - 5 | --> qualquer "c" dividido por 4 resulta em ímpar (descartando as decimais)
16  7 --> a - 5 |
...
32 23 --> a - 5
```

Logo:

```
var b = ~~(c/4)%2 == 0 ? a - 4 : a - 5;
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var a = 13,
    c = 6;

if (a - c == 7){
   
   var b = ~~(a/4)%2 == 0 ? a - 3 : a - 4;
   
   if (a - 3 == b){
      console.log("b igual a-3");
   } else
   if (a - 4 == b){
      console.log("b igual a-4");
   }
} else
if (a - c == 9){

   var b = ~~(c/4)%2 == 0 ? a - 4 : a - 5;

   if (a - 4 == b){
      console.log("b igual a-4");
   } else
   if (a - 5 == b){
      console.log("b igual a-5");
   }
}

console.log("b = "+b);
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função `calculaB` abaixo:

- Essa função recebe os dois números `a` e `c`e então escolhe os dois valores que estão no meio que podem ser `b`.
- Esses valores são obtidos ao calcular a média entre `a` e `c`, onde um deles é a média arredondada para baixo e o outro é a média arredondada para cima.
- Se ambos os valores coincidirem, apenas um é retornado. Se não coincidirem ambos são retornados, sendo o menor primeiro.

```js
function calculaB(a, c) {
    var media = (c + a) / 2;
    var b1 = Math.floor(media);
    var b2 = Math.ceil(media);
    return b1 === b2 ? [b1] : [b1, b2];
}

$("#calcular").click(function() {
    var a = parseInt($("#a").val());
    var c = parseInt($("#c").val());
    var bs = calculaB(a, c);
    $("#b").val(bs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label for="a">a:</label><input type="text" id="a" value="" /></div>
<div><label for="c">c:</label><input type="text" id="c" value="" /></div>
<div><button id="calcular">Calcular</button></div>
<div><label for="b">b:</label><input type="text" id="b" value="" readonly="true" /></div>
```

Clique no botão azul "Executar" para testar o código acima.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, vamos imaginar que o tabuleiro tivesse todas as 64 casas numeradas ao invés de apenas as 32 escuras. Para isso precisamos de uma função que converte o seu formato de numeração para um formato de numeração com as 64 casas. Aqui está essa função:

```
function recalcula32to64(casa) {
    return casa * 2 - (Math.floor((casa - 1) / 4) % 2 === 0 ? 0 : 1);
}
```

E também de uma função que faça o inverso:

```
function recalcula64to32(casa) {
    return casa % 2 === 0 ? casa / 2 : (casa + 1) / 2;
}
```

E então basta calcular qual é a casa do meio:

```
function calculaB(a, c) {
    return recalcula64to32((recalcula32to64(a) + recalcula32to64(c)) / 2);
}
```

```js
function recalcula32to64(casa) {
    return casa * 2 - (Math.floor((casa - 1) / 4) % 2 === 0 ? 0 : 1);
}

function recalcula64to32(casa) {
    return casa % 2 === 0 ? casa / 2 : (casa + 1) / 2;
}

function calculaB(a, c) {
    return recalcula64to32((recalcula32to64(a) + recalcula32to64(c)) / 2);
}

$("#calcular").click(function() {
    var a = parseInt($("#a").val());
    var c = parseInt($("#c").val());
    var bs = calculaB(a, c);
    $("#b").val(bs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><label for="a">a:</label><input type="text" id="a" value="" /></div>
<div><label for="c">c:</label><input type="text" id="c" value="" /></div>
<div><button id="calcular">Calcular</button></div>
<div><label for="b">b:</label><input type="text" id="b" value="" readonly="true" /></div>
```

Clique no botão azul "Executar" para testar o código acima.